# Create variable number gridviews in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to create multiple numbers of GridViews based on another selection.

I'm guessing that I can only do this on the code behind page. However, do I need to specify the ASP:GridView control in the .aspx page at all?

Below are my codes:

```
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                    sqlStatement = "select table_name, column_name, [Description], data_type from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE tableName = '" + dt.Rows[j][0].ToString()+ "'";

                command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);

                GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.DataSource = ds;
                Page.Controls.Add(gv); 
            }
            Page.DataBind(); 
        }
```

I tried running the code above but kept getting the error message:

```
Control 'ctl01' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

Comment: Yes, you don't need to specify the ASP:GridView control in the .aspx page. Have you specified it? How does the .aspx file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your form tag contains runat = "server"   ?

Answer (score 0):

You should always insert controls into PlaceHolders

Check this out:

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3826/adding-controls-to-placeholders-dynamically/

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix...I created a ASP.NET Panel called Panel1 in the aspx page and in the code behind, instead of `Page` I put Panel1.

Thanks for your help everyone!